# Xsetwacom -list devices having issues

Tags: command-line, gnome, xorg, wacom

Ok Hi first of all,

I am a new born linux user thanks to my uncle. I love it!

My only problem at the moment is this:

I have a Wacom Bamboo pen and touch CTH-460/k and have recently updated my Ubuntu.

Running Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome shell (uncle installed for me)

When I type in the terminal

```
xsetwacom -listdevices
```

I get this:

```
User@jUser-A6500:~$ xsetwacom –list devices
Usage: xsetwacom [options] [command [arguments...]]
Options:
 -h, --help                 - usage
 -v, --verbose              - verbose output
 -V, --version              - version info
 -d, --display "display"    - override default display
 -s, --shell                - generate shell commands for 'get'
 -x, --xconf                - generate xorg.conf lines for 'get'

Commands:
 --list devices             - display detected devices
 --list parameters          - display supported parameters
 --list modifiers           - display supported modifier and specific keys for keystrokes
 --set "device name" parameter [values...] - set device parameter by name
 --get "device name" parameter [param...]  - get current device parameter(s) value by name
```

It was giving me the standard run through of devices i.e Pen, stylus etc yesterday without trouble.

I use `xsetwacom -listdevices` to turn off my touch function for my artworks.

Now cant sooooo I am super frustrated.

Please and thank you to any that help T.T

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of Linux :)

Now, if I understand correctly, you just mis-typed the command. Take note that it is

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

(note the *two* minus symbols and "list devices" has a space in between).

---

Reading your question, you might want to look up how to set a keyboard shortcut to toggle between touch on and touch off. I believe that [the script on this page](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Wacom_Tablet_Set_Up#Bamboo_P.26T_Touch_Toggle_Script) might be of use to you

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Linux! :)
You can safely omit the two dashes in `list` and all other actions such as `get` and `set`. The program's behavior will stay the same and i find it more comfortable to write. Finally, a quick tip: *read very carefully every output you get from your machine and read a lot of man pages, especially when you are unsure about the sintax of certain commands*.